# Can't trigger AWS Lambda S3 trigger using localstack?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, localstack

My lambda function is not triggering while s3 events occur in localstack?

But it invokes when trigger it directly by using "sls invoke -f hello --stage local"

Help me to solve this issue?
I have attched my handler.js and serverless.yml file

SERVERLESS.yml

```
service: ls-node

frameworkVersion: '2'

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-localstack
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'development'}
  region: us-east-1
  profile: iamjai


  iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - s3:PutBucketNotification
          - s3:GetObject
        Resource: ["arn:aws:s3:::iamjai-dev/*"]

functions: 
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: iamjai-dev
          events: 
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
    environment:
      TEST_NAME: "iamjai"
      TEST_MAIL: "jai@jai.com"



custom:
  localstack:
    stages:
      - local
  bucket: iamjai-dev
  dotenv:
    path: ../.env
    basePath: ../
    logging: false
    # include:
    #   - CLIENT
    #   - DATE
```

handler.js

```
'use strict';
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ accessKeyId: "1234", secretAccessKey: "5678", 
     endpoint: 'http://localhost:4566', s3ForcePathStyle: true, bucketName: "iamjai-dev" });

const csv=require('csvtojson')

module.exports.hello = async event => {
  console.log("Executed!!!!!")
  const Bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const Key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
  const data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key }).promise();
  const params = {
            Bucket: Bucket,
            Key: Key,
          };
  const stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
  // convert csv file (stream) to JSON format data
  const jsonArray = await csv().fromStream(stream);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(stream))
  console.log(jsonArray.length);
  // console.log('NAME: ', process.env.NAME);
  // console.log('EMAIL: ', process.env.MAIL);
  console.log("Raw text:\n" + data.Body.toString('ascii'));
  
};
```

I need to trigger my lambda function when an file is uploaded in s3 bucket using localstack?